# Is there an Alternative to textvariable on ttk.Entry widget, for tk.Text widget on TK inter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

so according to Tkinter documentation, the purpose of an Entry widget is to allow the user to enter or edit **a single line of text**. I want to get enter and Edit multiple lines of text but there is a problem. The alternative suggested by tkinter, Text, doesn't do the job at all!

here is my code using ttk.Entry:

```
   def _set_project_description_frame(self):
        project_description_frame = ttk.Frame(self._main_frame)
        ttk.Label(project_description_frame, text="Project Description").pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor="nw")
        ttk.Entry(project_description_frame, textvariable=self._project_description).pack(side=tk.LEFT,
                                                                                          expand=True, fill=tk.X)
        return project_description_frame
```

This produces the following tkinter output:
[image]

but what I really wan is to have the description section actually look like a place where a description would go, so I replaced ttk.Entry with tk.Text:

```
def _set_project_description_frame(self):
    project_description_frame = ttk.Frame(self._main_frame)
    ttk.Label(project_description_frame, text="Project Description").pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor="nw")
    tk.Text(project_description_frame, height=5).pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.X)
    return project_description_frame
```

The result shown in the picture bellow:
[image]

The last result is exactly what I want but the problem is that without the passing `textvariable=self._project_description` to `tk.Text` it's impossible to actually save whatever is typed into that text field.

So my question is, how do I fix the code in order to be able to capture what's input into the text field the same way ttk.Entry does when I can't pass `textvariable=self._project_description` to it?

Comment: You can retrieve the contents of the `Text` widget with `get()` just as you would with an `Entry` widget. Realistically, you don't need to use `textvariable` with an `Entry` either, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `Text` widget doesn't support `textvariable` because a `Text` widget can contain more than just text. To get the content out of the `Text` widget you need to call the `get` method on the widget.

To get all of the contents of the widget you first need to keep a reference to the widget. Then it's just a matter of calling `get` with an index for the range of text you want. Typically the two indexes will be the strings `"1.0"` for the first character, and `"end-1c"` for the last character before the newline added by the text widget itself.

```
def _set_project_description_frame(self):
    ...
    self.text_widget = tk.Text(project_description_frame, height=5)
    self.text_widget.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.X)
    ...
```

With that, anywhere else in your code that needs to fetch the data can do this:

```
self.text_widget.get("1.0", "end-1c")
```

Comment: Alright, I try this approach and see how it goes, thanks